# How can I exploit the following code using string format vulnerabilities, Global offset table & GDB?

Tags: exploit, c, shellcode, privilege-escalation, format-string

The following code should be exploited and I need to exploit it in such a way that it runs my command (l33t) and there should be shellcode and exploit included, so that it runs my command. I believe I need to use GDB and it has something to do with the global offset table and is potentially a string format vulnerability (although I could be wrong). It is the C code shown below.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int sudoexec(char *command)
{
  FILE *f = NULL;
  char log_entry[64];
  char line[256];

  f = fopen("sudolog", "a");
  if (f == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open sudolog file\n");
      return -1;
    }
  snprintf(log_entry, 64, "%d: %s\n", getuid(), command);
  
  fprintf(f, log_entry, NULL);
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen("sudoers", "r");
  if (f == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open sudoers file\n");
      return -1;
    }

  while(fgets(line, 256, f) != NULL)
    { 
      if (atoi(line) == getuid())
        {
          if (setuid(0) == 0) {
            system(command);
          } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Setting the UID to root failed: check permissions\n");
          }

          fclose(f);
          return 0;
        }
    }
  fprintf(stderr, "User not listed in the sudoers file\n");
return -1;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

  if (argv[1] == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Missing args\n");
      return -1;
    }
  
  if (sudoexec(argv[1]) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute your command\n");
      return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Please share the exploit and shellcode and please explain the procedure used to exploit this code so that it ran my command (l33t).

Comment: Welcome to the community. What have you already researched and tried?

Comment: Hi Muffington, thank you. I honestly don't really know where to begin with this, unfortunately. As I don't program in C

Comment: The language doesn’t really matter. 

And you could start by learning C syntax…

Comment: If you do not know the language, we're not going to hand you a pre-made exploit. We can help with a specific problem, but we don't do "hack this for me please". And I'm guessing this is homework. We can help with homework, but you have to at least try to come up with an answer on your own.

Comment: okay, do you have any tips on how I can approach this?

Comment: @AM yes, analyze the code and find a possible vulnerability first.